# Splitting(Formatting) Binary String by Fours

Tags: python, string, loops, binary, format

Say we have a binary string: `bin = "11011"` 
How would I go about segmenting the binary string by fourths: `1 1011`

Normally splitting by fourths outputs `1011 1` instead:

```
for i in range(0, len(bin),4):
    print(bin[i:i+4], end=" ")

>> 1011 1
```

Although I found a bit messy way of doing it I was wondering if they was a more elegant solution to the problem:

```
mod = len(bin)%4
for s1 in range(mod, len(bin)+1,4):
    s0 = s1 - 4
    if s0 < 0:
        s0 = 0
    print(bin[s0:s1], end=" ")

>> 1 1011
```

or

```
bin = (4-len(bin)%4) * "0" + bin
for i in range(0, len(bin),4):
    print(bin[i:i+4], end=" ")

>> 0001 1011
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
>>> s = "10011"
>>> " ".join([s[::-1][i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(s), 4)])[::-1]
'1 0011'
```

`s[::-1` reverses the string (i.e. it becomes `11001`) and the list comprehension splits it into 4-digit length chunks.

The rest simply converts the list back to a string separated by spaces using `" ".join()` and reverses the string again so that the digits are in their original order.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty simple.
Just try this,

```
bin = "10011"
bin = bin[::-1]
ans = []
for i in range(0, len(bin), 4):
    ans.append(bin[i:i+4])
print(' '.join(ans)[::-1])
```

## Test Case:

Input: 10011

Output: 1 0011

Input: 111101010

Output: 1 1110 1010